# me salta un "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python

En el siguiente codigo:

```
import sys
if len (sys . argv) == 2 :
numero = int (sys . argv[ 1 ])
if numero < 0 or numero > 9999 :
print ( "Error - Número es incorrecto" )
print ( "Ejemplo: descomposicion.py [0-9999]" )
else :
# Aqui va la lógica
cadena = str (numero)
longitud = len (cadena)
for i in range (longitud):
print ( "{:04d}" . format( int (cadena[longitud -1- i]) * 10 ** i ))
else :
print ( "Error - Argumentos incorrectos" )
print ( "Ejemplo: descomposicion.py [0-9999]" )
```

me salta:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: For favor indenta acá tal cual está indentado en tu código

Comment: El error es muy correcto. __Debes__ usar tabulaciones o espacios para identar el código en Python. Te recomiendo que busques un tutorial de iniciación. Tu código tiene demasiados errores de formato como para poder corregirlo. Edita tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien menciono @toledano deberia identar tu codigo aunque claro en la actualidad muchos editores te proporciona mucha ayuda en ese aspecto.

Siguiendo un poco la logica de tu programa el codigo quedaria asi.

```
import sys


if len (sys.argv) == 2 :

    numero = int (sys . argv[ 1 ])

    if numero < 0 or numero > 9999 :
        print ( "Error - Número es incorrecto" )
        print ( "Ejemplo: descomposicion.py [0-9999]" )
    else:
        cadena = str (numero)
        longitud = len (cadena)

        for i in range (longitud):
            print ( "{:04d}".format( int (cadena[longitud -1- i]) * 10 ** i ))
else :
    print ( "Error - Argumentos incorrectos" )
    print ( "Ejemplo: descomposicion.py [0-9999]" )
```

Comment: vale muchas gracias,así me funciona perfectamente,y perdonar que llevo solo 2 semanas con python y aun no me entiendo muy bien :D

Comment: Ya, a mí también me ha dado ese error, puede ser por un problema de espacios? Yo también soy nuevo en python pero ya he tocado otros lenguajes como ahora  JS y veo que aquí no existen los '{}'. Y que estos son reemplazados por espacios? es eso cierto? Como funcionan?