# expected an idented block

Tags: python

Hola  maestros programadores tengo este pequeño programa pero en la linea despues de if **name** == '**main**': me marca error dice expected an idented block y la verdad no logro saber porque me dijieron que el maind e debia ponerlo al principio pero no se:

```
class Estudiante():
    def __init__(self):
        self. _atencion(self)
        self._apunta(self)
        self._realiza(self)
        self._entrega(self)
            
    def _atencion(self):
        print("El estudiante pone atencion")

    def _apunta(self):
        print("El estudiante toma sus apuntes")

    def _realiza (self):
        print ("El estudiante realiza su tarea")

    def _entrega(self):
        print ("El estudiante entrega su tarea")


if __name__ == '__main__':
estu. = Estudiante()
estu._atencion()
estu._apunta()
estu._realiza()
estu._entrega()
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expected an idented block](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485111/expected-an-idented-block)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [me salta un "IndentationError: expected an indented block"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/55396/me-salta-un-indentationerror-expected-an-indented-block)

Answer (score 0):

tu bloque de codigo no esta indentado, python usa indentación para saber a que bloque pertenece determinado bloque de codigo. debe ir asi.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    estu. = Estudiante()
    estu._atencion()
    estu._apunta()
    estu._realiza()
    estu._entrega()
```